# Does overlapping subscriptions in Meteor make performance worse?

Tags: meteor, meteor-publications

Here is my issue.

I have an app where users can store notes in notepads.

Currently when the user clicks a notepad, I subscribe to a publication which returns that notepads first 5 notes.

So whenever the user navigates to a new notepad, a new subscription is set and the 5 notes of that notepad end up in minimongo. So minimongo only has 5 notes in the notes collection at a time

To improve user experience, I changed the publication so upon the initial load of the entire app, I subscribe to a publication which returns all notepads and the first 5 notes for each notepad. So now in minimongo we have (5 x (# of notepads)) number of notes at all times.

So the initial load is a bit heavier but I am hoping that after that, navigating between notepads is much faster.

So upon load I subscribe to `myInfo` which returns the users notepads and fist 5 notes for each notepad.

Then when you actually click a notepad, I subscribe to `myNotepadInfo`, which also returns the first 5 notes of the notepad. Since the initial subscription has already retrieved this info, none of the documents in minimongo actually change. But I still want to subscribe to `myNotepadInfo` because the I have a load more notes mechanism which depends on that subscription in the template.

So my app is fully working with these changes but I am not sure what is going on under the hood, and if this method is actually helping performance. I can't notice a concrete difference in how notepads load after the change.

So basically I have a second subscription which overlaps which the initial subscription.

To me it seems like since the second subscription overlaps with the initial one, it has to transfer less documents to the client, so it should be faster?

Comment: From [meteor documentation](https://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html#Meteor-subscribe): '*However, if the next iteration of your run function subscribes to the same record set (same name and parameters), Meteor is smart enough to skip a wasteful unsubscribe/resubscribe.*'
I don't think it is good practice to subscribe to everything on startup. Your load time will strongly increase with a lot of notepad. That's why the subscription are for. If further ahead you want to implement a dynamic load/search, [easy:search](https://github.com/matteodem/meteor-easy-search) is a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

Two key questions for this will be (1) how much data are you sending down to the client?; and (2) how many users are you expecting?

The second point calls for some explanation. A key component in Meteor's current (2016) pub sub architecture is that client subscriptions are registered and tracked on the server. Each additional subscription that cannot be reused (i.e. does not duplicate another subscription) will increase the CPU requirements for the app. Here, it sounds like each user "owns" a notepad (though that might not be the case). If so, it will mean low subscription reuse -- each user will require an independent subscription to receive his/her notepad, as they cannot be reused across users. Hence two notepad subscriptions per user will effectively double the portion of the CPU footprint of the app that is owing to notepad subscriptions.

That is not necessarily a bad thing. If your app is designed for administration, in house services, or simply a lower numbers of users, it might not make an appreciable difference. For a consumer-facing app hoping for / expecting high user numbers, it would be a bad choice.

A good article by Kadira on observer reuse [is here](https://kadira.io/academy/meteor-performance-101/content/improve-cpu-and-network-usage) and I also recommend their (paid) Bulletproof Meteor articles.

Finally, you could check out some of the Kadira tools that are meant to improve these issues, [Subs Manager](https://github.com/kadirahq/subs-manager) and [Fast Render](https://github.com/kadirahq/fast-render). You should check out whether they are still being actively maintained, though - I haven't.

Comment: Hi Jeremy thanks this is helpful. The user does subscribe to their own information. In the publication I return the notepad and notes by using `this.userId` in the query. How else would I do this? I don't understand, it seems that this would be the only way to subscribe to your own data. There is no way to set it up to so users share a subscription. Am I missing anything?

Comment: I don't think you're missing anything. If you're doing something like `return Notepads.find({userId: this.userId})` in your publication you won't be able to reuse observers so you're better off with the first of the two strategies you outlined in the question. Two subscriptions per notepad per user will lead to CPU issues sooner, which is a main Meteor scaling bottleneck. (The only thing that will slightly increase efficiency is to do a null check for this.userId, which is referenced in the Kadira article linked above, and that's not really addressing the main issue.)